# Issue in indexing gurobi matrix variable in constraints in python

Tags: python, gurobi

I am working on an optimization problem. I have an issue in indexing the gurobi matrix variable in the constraint part. I am unable to solve the matrix dimension issue. Could anybody have a look at my script and guide me on how to fix it?

```
#In the nested loop of the constraint part:
Ts*np.linalg.inv(M)@Bu@dDelta)@useq[i-k-2]+s1[:,k]
```

I am getting an incompatible dimension error because of the s1 variable. However, I am slicing the s1 matrix 3 by 1 which is of size 3x5 already defined. I don't understand where I am wrong. Thank you very much in advance.

```
#python code
N=5
m=gp.Model("matrix")
Ts=0.2
M=np.eye(3)
D=np.eye(3)
C=np.eye(3)
Bu=np.array((3,4)
pos=np.array([0,0,0]).T
u=np.array([0,0,0,0]).T

xseq=[]
xseq.append(pos)
useq=[]

#1st loop
for i in range (1,N+1):
    xseq.append(pos)
    useq.append(u)

#2nd loop
for i in range(N+1,7):
    s1=m.addMVar((3,N))   #s1 matrix of 3x5
    A=np.eye(3)
    deltaBut1=m.addVar(1)
    deltaBut2=m.addVar(1)
    deltaBut3=m.addVar(1)
    deltaBut4=m.addVar(1)
    deltaBut=np.array([deltaBut1,deltaBut2,deltaBut3,deltaBut4]).T
    
   dDelta=np.diag(deltaBut)
   obj1=0
   
   for k in range(0,N):    # N=5
       m.addConstr(xseq[i-k-1]-A@xseq[i-k-2]==(Ts*np.linalg.inv(M)@Bu@dDelta)@useq[i-k-2]+s1[:,k])
       obj1=obj1+s1[:,k]@s1[:,k]
   
   m.setObjective(10**3*(obj1))
   m.optimize
```

The constraints that I am implementing is shown in this figure:

[image]

In the current, I am not considering the `Bu*f(t-1)` part.

In the constraint part, the left side gives a 3x1 shape while the right side gives MLinExpr of shape (3,). Could anybody help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This isn't really a Gurobi problem. `Bu` has shape `(2,)` while `dDelta` has shape `(4,4)`, so you can't compute the vector-matrix product `Bu @ dDelta`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sorry it was my mistake. Bu is 3x4 and dDelta is 4x4. The problem was with s1 that is MVar object. By considering var object the issue is solved.